# How are packets routed from my VirtualBox Virtual Machine to my local host OS environment?

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I have a basic question I do not understand regarding the IP given to a Virtual Machine running on my laptop. I use [`boot2docker`](http://boot2docker.io) (basically, it creates a VirtualBox Virtual Machine to have access to Docker on my Mac). The IP of the created Virtual Machine:

```
boot2docker ip  // IP of the vm created
```

Gives me `192.168.59.103`, where my local IP address is is `192.168.1.21`.

I run a little website within the Virtual Machine and it is accessible from my local machine’s browser at the URL: `http://192.168.59.103`

My very basic network knowledge made me think that only `192.168.1.x` addresses are accessible from my local machine. Why is `192.168.59.103` visible?

Comment: How on earth do we know?  At the very least, the output of `netstat -rn` and `ifconfig -a` (or OS-equivalent) on both client and server would be a start in answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My very basic network knowledge made me think that only `192.168.1.x`
>   addresses are accessible from my local machine. Why is
>   `192.168.59.103` visible?

No. Not at all. If that were the case, than how were you able to visit this website or any website on the Internet via your computer?

Specific to your case, your local IP address of `192.168.1.21` is an address assigned—most likely via DHCP—from your LAN’s router.

But then the `192.168.59.103` is a network on your desktop—within the confines of your computer and only your computer—that operates on the VirtualBox virtual “router” range of `192.168.59.x`. Meaning when you launch Virtual Box it’s not just providing a virtualization environment, it is also *emulating* basic networking/router functionality.

Not too sure how your Docker setup works, but if you were to launch the Virtual Box application interface and then select to your specific virtual machine and then select “Network” you will see that the settings for one of the active adapters should be “NAT” which of course stands for Network Address Translation and [as explained in the official Virtual Box documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat_service) which is titled “Virtual networking” (big hint):

> The Network Address Translation (NAT) service works in a similar way
>   to a home router, grouping the systems using it into a network and
>   preventing systems outside of this network from directly accessing
>   systems inside it, but letting systems inside communicate with each
>   other and with systems outside using TCP and UDP over IPv4 and IPv6.

Simple as that. Virtual Box has it’s own software emulated router baked into it’s core networking code to handle NAT and other routing.

So when you launch a Virtual Box guest OS machine—via Docker or anything else—and you connect to it, you are really connecting to it via the small, isolated network router that exists *only* on your desktop.

Now if you wanted to have that guest OS to connect outside of you local desktop, there are many ways you could do that. But that’s far past the scope of this question’s context. Default Virtual Box behavior is to create a network on your desktop just for your use in connecting to the guest OS machines it is running/managing.

Answer (score 3):

If you have noticed, when you were installing the virtualbox, it told you that your network connections might be interrupted because it was going to install a **virtual network adapter** in your computer. So check your current network adapters, you will find those virtual ones.

Now check the IP address of those virtual adapters, you will find that a IP 192.168.59.X is assgiend to one of them. So you are connecting to those virtual instances using this network adapter. It is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, ifconfig shows me some additional interface, one of which is:

" vboxnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00
 inet 192.168.59.3 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.59.255 ".

But is there some kind of virtual bridge that bridges the 192.168.1.0 with 192.168.59.0 without sending the packet out to the gateway ?

Comment: Using the "route PRINT" command to print your route table. It will answer your question. Since you have two interface assigned with either IP, your windows system will choose the proper interface to go depends on which sub network you are going to access